# Detect exact imageview from many imageviews

Tags: iphone

I create 5 imageviews with different images using tag value. Now i wants to determine the currently touched imageview in touches Began method.

Pls anybody help with guide.

Comment: have you looked into a UIGestureRecognizer?  Is there a reason you are using touchesBegan?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

In touch began method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[touches allTouches]anyObject]; // Picks up the touch
NSLog(@"touched view%@",[touch view]);
UIView *view=[touch view];//here you can find the view which is touched and after that you can compare it with your image views like
if(view==(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1])
{
//first image view touched
}
}
//you can proceed in this way.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Shanmu please accept and vote up the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [[touches allTouches]anyObject]; // Picks up the touch
  UIImageView *view=(UIImageView *)[touch view];//here you can find the view which is touched and after that you can compare it with your image views like
 if(view){

      if([view tag] == 0)
      {
          //UIImageView with tag 0 touched
      }
      else if([view tag] == 1)
      {
          //UIImageView with tag 1 touched
      }
      else if([view tag] == 2)
      {
          //UIImageView with tag 2 touched
      }
      else if([view tag] == 3)
      {
          //UIImageView with tag 3 touched
      }
      else if([view tag] == 4)
      {
          //UIImageView with tag 4 touched
      }
    }
  }
}
```